# How to override third party module css into custom module

Tags: overrides, magento2.4.1

I am using a third-party module, i did model and template files override, how to override CSS in the custom module.

Under web/css folder i am created three custom less file, how to rewrite from the custom module?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html#override-module-styles

You can do it directly in theme or create a module if you want to change something else (more than only css)

Considering its only css:

**to Override:**
<theme_dir>/
<module_dir>/
web/
css/
source/_module.less

**to Just append new CSS' rules:**
<theme_dir>/
<module_dir>/
web/
css/
source/_extend.less

Comment: I am created a custom module module and override model and template files, how to override css?

Comment: In the third-party module the CSS rules are in view/<base|front/back end>/web/css/source/_module.less? Or there is a .css file in somewhere?